# How do I move Interchange?

Tags: mini-metro

So I've built one -- now how do I cancel it to rebuild in another place? I can rebuild tracks and move trains my drag'n'drop but it seems like I can't do that with Interchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know from playing the game, once you place an interchange its permanent.